# Index was out of range exception when attempting to access Worksheets object

Tags: epplus

I have an .XLSX created by a 3rd party.  I can read it in Excel just fine, however if I try to read it with EPPlus, I get the following exception:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelStyle..ctor(ExcelStyles styles, ChangedEventHandler ChangedEvent, Int32 positionID, String Address, Int32 xfsId)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Style.XmlAccess.ExcelNamedStyleXml..ctor(XmlNamespaceManager NameSpaceManager, XmlNode topNode, ExcelStyles styles)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelStyles.LoadFromDocument()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelStyles..ctor(XmlNamespaceManager NameSpaceManager, XmlDocument xml, ExcelWorkbook wb)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.get_Styles()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.get_MaxFontWidth()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.get_DefaultColWidth()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.LoadColumns(XmlReader xr)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.CreateXml()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet..ctor(XmlNamespaceManager ns, ExcelPackage excelPackage, String relID, Uri uriWorksheet, String sheetName, Int32 sheetID, Int32 positionID, eWorkSheetHidden hide)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheets..ctor(ExcelPackage pck, XmlNamespaceManager nsm, XmlNode topNode)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.get_Worksheets()
```

If I open the file in Excel and then save it as a new file, EPPlus can read the file just fine.  Obviously, this is not a solution that is reasonable for the end users of my system.

I can send the file to the developers if they need, or I can provide more diagnostic information if needed and available.

I'm going to check in with the developers of the other app to try to figure out what API they are using to generate the .XLSX.

code:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(importEquipmentFile.InputStream))
{
   foreach (var ws in package.Workbook.Worksheets.Where(ws => ws.Hidden == eWorkSheetHidden.Visible))
    ...
```

and this simplified blows up too:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(importEquipmentFile.InputStream))
{
   foreach (var ws in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
   ...
```

---

Here's the problem.  In the code below

positionID = -1 and _styles.CellStyleXfs list is empty, so the "else" gets called

```
    internal ExcelStyle(ExcelStyles styles, OfficeOpenXml.XmlHelper.ChangedEventHandler ChangedEvent, int positionID, string Address, int xfsId) :
        base(styles, ChangedEvent, positionID, Address)
    {
        Index = xfsId;
        ExcelXfs xfs;
        if (positionID > -1)
        {
            xfs = _styles.CellXfs[xfsId];
        }
        else
        {
            xfs = _styles.CellStyleXfs[xfsId];
        }
```

and that throws an exception because the code that's called can't handle an empty list.

```
   public T this[int PositionID]
    {
        get
        {
            return _list[PositionID]; // <<<--- this blows up because _list has no members
        }
    }
```

I tweaked the code to be this, and it worked OK, but I'm not sure of the best way to deal with that list being empty:

```
if (positionID > -1 || _styles.CellStyleXfs.Count == 0)
```

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: Can you share the problematic file?

Comment: yes, but not publicly

Comment: If you cannot share the file I think your best bet would be to download the Epplus source code and run the file through it. From the call stack it looks like something is up with the defined Style in the worksheet/workbook XML which can get pretty complicated.

Comment: yeah, I decided over dinner that I was going to pull the source down and put it in my test site and step through the debugger--heck, I've used this and would love to give back to the community :)

Comment: I created a issue on the EPPlus github project